# Need to make a keypress without pressing enter

Tags: java, awt, keypress

I am making a program using NetBeans. Is it possible to make a key press method without pressing enter?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.

Comment: you mean you want it in one line in java source ? elaborate it more

Comment: Do you want to simulate somebody pressing the Enter key?

Comment: The program need to read a letter that is pressed from the user from keyboard without the user have to press the ENTER button. Is there any method to make this?

Answer (score 3):

The [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyPress%28int%29) class has methods that make this fairly easy:

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

If I had understand your question correctly, you need to simulate keypress event. If that is the case you need to use Robot class. See here for more information [Robot Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)

Comment: I need to make this method that recognize which button is pressed and does not wait the user to press enter.

Comment: @hariru22, yes you use Robot class for the same. If you go through API you will get it.